# How cleanup openstack orphan stuff and manage trash?

Tags: openstack, cleanup, orphans

We start use Openstack some months ago, and realize that delete projects does not delete project content! we periodically create projects for users groups and delete when are not needed anymore, but there are orphan vms, keypairs and other stuff registered in the Openstack database and listed using administration account, how deal with that? besides carefully delete everything inside a project before delete, there is any advice to free those trash?

Answer (score 0):

I think `$ openstack project purge` may be what you are looking for.
https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/command-objects/project-purge.html